# Can't get javadocs to display in IntelliJ IDEA (Android with Maven build)

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, javadoc

I have imported an Android project (with a Maven build) into IntelliJ IDEA and the javadocs aren't showing up when I hover my mouse over the text in the editor. To be clear, it isn't my inline documentation settings that is the problem, it pulls up the 'Documentation' tooltip just fine. But the tooltip window is mostly empty except for the method signature and package.

Below are screenshots of what happens when I hover my mouse over the text, and my Project Structure:

[image]

[image]

FTR my Documentation Paths in the Project Structure were totally empty at the start except for pointing to a /reference folder that contains no .jar files (and did not work either), the .jar files currently there were my attempt at importing the javadocs (which also failed).

Three questions:

1. Which javadoc file do I need to import to get the documentation to
   work?
2. Will I need to import additional javadoc files for all the
   additional packages like Android support library, etc?
3. Is it normal to need to import these javadocs manually all the time or
   should they automatically show up? Does this point to a larger issue with my Maven import or build process?

**Edit:** I already have the documentation for API 23 downloaded in my SDK manager as well.

Also, it seems my Maven libraries have errors in the Javadocs linked. Below is an example. Does that mean I also have to re-link my Maven libraries to the correct Javadocs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open up your SDK Manager and download the documentation for the specific SDKs that you need. To answer your questions:

1. Download the documentation for the latest SDK (aleast): [image]
2. Yes, you need to import documentation for every library you add, but the least you should have is the documentation for your latest SDK. Most recent documentation usually has the documentation for earlier APIs included and also describes any recommended changes, deprecations, etc.
3. It is absolutely normal to download the javadoc normally. There is no error in your build process or imports

Comment: I already have the documentation for API 23 downloaded in my SDK Manager though. The issue seems to be that the documentation path is not pointed to the correct documentation.